# test count of react components within a component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a form in which I have two Select Components. I am trying to write a test to check if Form is rendering both the components.

short code snippet for **FormComponent**:

```
export class FormComponent extends Component {

render() {
        return (
            <Form header="hdr">
                <SelectField
                            label='lable1'
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
                            />

                 <SelectField
                            label='label2'
                            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
                            />
           </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

short code snippet for **SelectField**:

```
export const SelectField = (props) => <FormField label={props.label}>
                                        <Select />
                                      </FormField>
```

code snippet for **the test**:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount, render, shallow } from "enzyme";
import { FormComponent } from "../../../src/components/mdm/FormComponent";
import { SelectField } from "../../../src/components/mdm/SelectField";

describe("FormComponent", () => {
  it('renders components', () => {
    const element = shallow(<FormComponent />);
    expect(element.find(SelectField)).to.have.lengthOf(2);
  });
});
```

---

I am getting below **error**:

```
 FAIL  test/components/mdm/FormComponent.test.jsx
  FormComponent
    ✕ renders components (74ms)

  ● FormComponent › renders components

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

      18 |     const element = shallow(<FormComponent />);
    > 19 |     expect(element.find(SelectField)).to.have.lengthOf(2);
```

I tried with **mount** as well but same error.

I even did **console.log** in test `console.log(element.debug())` which was showing the component, log output:

```
    <Form header="hdr">
          <SelectField label="lable1" onChange={[Function]} />
          <SelectField label="label2" onChange={[Function]} />
```

---

Though `expect(element.find(SelectField).exists()).toBeTruthy();` works!

Comment: use `mount` instead of `shallow`, see if it renders. You did console.log on what in test or component?

Comment: @Rikin **mount** also fails with same error. I did `console.log(element.debug())` in test (The strange thing is it shows the elements in the log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expect(element.find(SelectField).length).toEqual(2);` worked!

I don't know what's the difference between **toEqual** and **to.have.lengthOf** but *toEqual* works but *lengthOf* doesn't work.